# Какой-то трик, чтобы ввод с второй клавиатуры читался только программой?

Tags: linux, debian, клавиатура

Сканер штрих-кода работает в режиме эмуляции клавиатуры. То есть это как еще одну клавиатуру подключили. Появляется устройство `/dev/hidraw1`. Могу с него читать следующим кодом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/hidraw1", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("error opening device: %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[256];
    int bytes;
    while (1) {
        bytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        if (bytes == -1) break;
        printf("read %d bytes\n", bytes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Но, если это запустить в консоли, то дополнительно в консоль автоматически выводится результат распознавания, а нужно, чтобы его получала только моя программа и даже нигде не показывала. То есть, чтобы вторая клавиатура вела себя просто как устройство, с которого можно что-то прочитать.

Comment: Не понял, что именно выводится в консоль? Содержимое `buffer`?

Comment: @avp, устройство `hidraw1` это (как) вторая клавиатура. То есть автоматически пишет туда, на чем фокус. Как это отключить можно?

Comment: Попробуйте `stty -F /dev/hidraw1 raw -echo`

Comment: а случаем ему evdev'овское устройство в `/dev/input/` в помощь не создаётся? и если в итоге тачка будет работать с X'ами, то можно банально их средствами ввод отключить...

Comment: *если это запустить в консоли* — речь точно о виртуальной консоли, а не об иксовом эмуляторе терминала? если о втором, то, к примеру, можно отключить устройство ввода: `xinput --disable id-устройства`. `id` можно получить, например, из вывода программы `xinput`